# ways of including WHERE clause into SELECT

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, conditional-statements

I am not sure if it is possible but I would like to `SELECT` only the data from a column whose `length` is `> 0`

so I know I can do it in the `where` `clause`,ie:

```
SELECT charNumber
FROM   tbl1
WHERE  len(charNumber) > 0
```

;

All of my friends told me there is no way to do this in SELECT, but I wanted to ask you guys if you knew a way.

I thought perhaps, `CASE WHEN` would work, but I don't want `CASE WHEN ''` and `CASE WHEN <= 0`
I only want `charNumber`'s that are `> 0`

`WHERE` clause is not an option since I am using d2rq that is not supporting anything that's in WHERE clause.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. If you put your condition in `WHERE` clause, you `SELECT` only desired data defined in `WHERE` clause. Where is the problem?

Comment: I am trying to bypass WHERE because D2RQ:condition doesn't support WHERE clause for sql server. I want to exclude values whose length is 0, but I can't find the way to do it within SELECT part... @Aycan

Comment: I'm not a D2RQ expert but I think filtering has to be done using its mapping language 
Example:
map:Paper a d2rq:ClassMap;
    d2rq:class :Paper;
    d2rq:uriPattern "http://www.conference.org/conf02004/paper#Paper@@Papers.PaperID@@";
    d2rq:condition "Papers.Publish = 1";
    d2rq:dataStorage map:Database1;

Answer (score 1):

Your friends are correct.  The `SELECT` clause has ***no*** control over how many rows are returned, it only controls what goes into the columns of those rows.

The `WHERE`, `FROM` and `HAVING` clauses can directly control which and how many rows are returned.

The `GROUP BY` clause can *indirectly* control what rows are returned.

Comment: I really don't care about how many rows are returned. Maybe my question is not clear.. I am trying to do something that's probably impossible...include condition inside SELECT